# Адаптировать изображение под смартфон

Tags: javascript, html, css, адаптивная-верстка

Есть одно изображение для компьютера ,а второе для мобильной версии. Как скриптом или css указать чтоб *если нужно разрешение для компьютера то подставляло один файлик с изображением,а если меньше то подставляло файлик с изображением для мобильной версии* .
Как реализовать такую вещь?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Может, `picture` + `srcset` ?https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture. В общем прописывайте `media` для разных разрешений экрана

Comment: Но это на сколько я знаю подходит для imges,а если у меня SVG ?

Comment: ?????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????? Тогда зачем вам разные файлы????????????????????????????????????

Comment: Сейчас скину - поймешь.погодь

Comment: получаеться первый вариант для пк (ноута),а второй для телефона

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
​<picture>
 <source srcset="pic2.svg" type="image/svg+xml" media="(min-width: 600px)">
 <img src="pic1.svg" alt="">
</picture>
```

Comment: Через <object> нельзя?

Comment: Можно, но без `picture`)

Comment: Так ? ​<object>
 <source srcset="pic2.svg" type="image/svg+xml" media="(min-width: 600px)>
 <img src="pic1.svg" alt="">
</object>

Answer (score 0):

Посоветую вам 1.

```css
img {
 width-max: *Максимальный размер фото в ширину*
 height-max: *Максимальный размер фото в высоту*
 width: auto;
 height: auto;
}
```

а так же советую попробовать это

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```